# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания (2)?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

Всем здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, в предложении: "Оценка адекватности и достоверности созданной численной компьютерной модели статического режима работы вальца АМД путем сравнения значений индукции магнитного поля в выбранных контрольных точках", нужны ли запятые после словосочетания "адекватности и достоверности" и после словосочетания "вальца АМД"? Это можно считать уточняющей конструкцией предложения?

Comment: Ваша запись не похожа на предложение. Если это фрагмент, то приведите полный вариант.

Comment: выглядит как автоперевод текста

Comment: А грамматическая основа какая?  Оценка – подлежащее, а сказуемое где?

Comment: @Sharon Может, это название статьи, тема исследования, задача и пр.

Comment: Разве можно так записать название или тему? Надо бы короче и  понятнее. А здесь какой-то набор речевых отрезков (иои синтагм, если можно так выразиться).

Comment: @Sharon  Названия (темы) диссертаций, дипломных работ ещё длиннее бывают :).  Но здесь, конечно, перебор с цепочкой родительного падежа.

Comment: Ну если только это диссертация о жуках))  Наверное, это розыгрыш. Видели, как вопрос был написан? А ведь автор знает об"уточняющих конструкциях предложения"?  Ну разве я не Шерлок Холмс?  Может, мне психологом стать...

Comment: @Sharon Извините, не совсем разобрался в сайте, не сразу понял, что тут есть комментарии под записью. Нет, это полноценное предложение, т.е. есть перечень работ, потом двоеточие, потом идет перечисление, одна работа из перечня именно так и называется. Нет, это не розыгрыш, это просто для себя удостовериться в правильности написания предложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это название работы, то это **номинативная конструкция** (без сказуемого):

*Оценка адекватности и **достоверности** / созданной численной компьютерной **модели** / статического режима работы **вальца АМД** / путем сравнения значений индукции магнитного поля / в выбранных контрольных точках.*

Читается сложно, но специалистам такая запись, наверное, понятна. Дополнительные знаки, как я думаю, здесь **не нужны**. Слеши стоят на месте **произносительных** пауз, они **не обозначаются** запятыми.

**Уточняющих** конструкций нет, все словосочетания входят в **основное** содержание предложения.

Вот как выглядит **структура предложения** (без распространителей):

*Оценка адекватности и **достоверности** модели режима работы **вальца АМД** / путем сравнения.*

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Ответ мне помог!

Answer (score 0):

Фраза выглядит как плохой перевод, либо содержит излишние слова или обороты.

Оценка адекватности и достоверности созданной численной компьютерной модели статического режима работы вальца АМД путем сравнения значений индукции магнитного поля в выбранных контрольных точках.

Оценка адекватности и достоверности - это как согласовать?

Для согласование нужно хотя бы предлоги расставить, иначе текст сплошняком выглядит как мясо.

Проверка адекватности и оценка достоверности получаемых данных от(?) - может так? Хотя адекватность - это что? как выражается адекватность?

от созданной численной компьютерной модели

модель или численная или компьютерная - вместе это тавтология. Созданной - а это вообще нужно слово?

От компьютерной модели.

статического режима работы вальца АМД...

от компьютерной модели вальца АМД, работающей в режиме статистики..

Проверка адекватности и оценка достоверности получаемых данных от компьютерной модели вальца АМД, работающей в режиме статистики, путём сравнения результатов измерения магнитной индукции в выбранных контрольных точках.